# How to copy a google drive document from one folder to another using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have two folders `Folder1` and `Folder2` in my Google drive.

I have created a google drive document `doc1` in Folder1. Later i need to copy this document to Folder2. How can i achieve this.

I tried the below link but its creating the copy on the same folder.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy

```
/**
 * Copy an existing file.
 *
 * @param {String} originFileId ID of the origin file to copy.
 * @param {String} copyTitle Title of the copy.
 */
function copyFile(originFileId, copyTitle) {
  var body = {'title': copyTitle};
  var request = gapi.client.drive.files.copy({
    'fileId': originFileId,
    'resource': body
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log('Copy ID: ' + resp.id);
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you got the answer, if yes Please share?

Answer (score 0):

As I have read on this [blog](https://ctrlq.org/code/19975-move-file-between-folders), there is no direct method to move files from one folder to another in Google Drive. Your option is to copy a file to another folder, set its name to the original file and then delete the original using the [setTrashed(true) method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setTrashed(Boolean)) of File.

Be noted that this method will fail if the file/s have been uploaded by another user while the script is running under a different user.

Here is a sample snippet:

```
function copyFile(originFileId, destinationFileId) {

  var files = originFileId.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(target).setName(file.getName());
    file.setTrashed(true);

  }
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hackaround in 2020. Go to Google Colab and use
`! cp path1 path2`

You can even use -r option for directories. Pretty neat!
Though I should warn you this method is slow if your folder contains a lot of files or contains large files.

Edit: typo in Colab